# position oriented text and image save in Django/mysql

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, django-models, relational-database

I'm creating a blog application similar to scoopwhoop or mensxp.

Basically I want to create my database in such a way that I can assign image a particular position in the article.

look at this page  https://www.scoopwhoop.com/Move-Over-Tony-Stark-Marvels-New-Iron-Man-Is-A-15YearOld-Black-Girl/

or http://www.mensxp.com/health/weight-loss/31372-5-rules-of-fat-loss-that-most-people-ignore.html

you see, in these pages we have some text then a relevant image then again some text and relevant image to just above text and so on.

I mean it should make sense that a particular image comes just before or after the related text.

Currently I'm doing this way

```
class Post(TimeStamp):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='full text description')
    # some more fields

class Pictures(TimeStamp):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_image_path)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="picture")
```

this schema will create two tables one for blog post and other of images used in posts.

now here I can randomly put images in a post... like count no of words in a post and number of images associated with this post and then use basic math to divide the text in equal length and put images after every blog  in frontend. but it wont solve the problem.

I tried to use [django_summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) as well but created some other problems so discarded that option.

How do you think I should design my schema so that I can solve this problem and may be i should be able to use django admin smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw out the Pictures() class altogether. The images should be a part of your post body. So an example entry would be...

**title** = "How to program an awesome site with Django!"

**text** = "`<p>This is some text.</p><img src='image link'><p>This is some text after the image</p>`"

Basically, the images are just as much a part of the post body as the text. There is no need to create a separate database table.

So in summary, this should be your database setup...

```
class Post(TimeStamp):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
     text = models.TextField(verbose_name='full text description')
     # some more fields
```

And the post body as a whole should all be contained within the **text** field.

Comment: This is what django_sumernote does.  but it's html specific. I mean <img> tag and all would work fine in html but not in windows or ios or android app, if we are using json api? i know there are parser in android or ios but they have limited functionaity

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are currently storing inside of the "text" field? How are you formatting the posts?